# What is the proper way I can invoke firefox from a python3 program?

Tags: python, firefox, operating-system

I'm trying to start firefox with an internet page by calling it in python 3 as an argument to os.system or os.startfile.

The internet page I want to start is https://schwab.com

I can't bring it up at the command line with

C:\Python34\hsf\WSC>C:\Program Files(x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe https://schwab.com

It chokes on the spaces.

But I can by using

C:\Progra~2\Mozill~1\firefox.exe https://schwab.com

That works fine at the command line

So I put that address as the argument to os.system in my python program, and got the error:

'C:\Progra~2\Mozill~1' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I tried it in os.startfile and got the error message:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1482, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)

File "C:\Python34\hsf\WSC\fm.py", line 59, in Schwab

```
res=os.startfile('C:\Progra~2\Mozill~1\firefox.exe https://schwab.com')
```

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:

'C:\Progra~2\Mozill~1\x0cirefox.exe https://schwab.com'

Note that it echoed my argument correctly, but the FileNotFoundError has inserted the string x0cire between '\' and 'firefox'

I deleted and retyped the '\f', and got the same erroroneous string inserted.

To avoid the path, I copied firefox.exe into my folder, but it won't run outside its native milieu.

What is the proper way I can invoke firefox from a python3 program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you want to do with this site. If all you want to do is open the page use the [webbrowser module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open) to open the url.

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('https://www.schwab.com/')
```

If you need to something more complicated, you can use the [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) module to interact with the page in pretty much anyway you need.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("selenium")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Wow! That's so easy it seems like cheating. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you try [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) a web driver API for Python, which works with Firefox, Chrome and many more. You can completely control the browser in addition to what you need!